# Exim4 скорость обработки очереди

Tags: php, email, exim, exim4

С помощью дерективы **acl_not_smtp** и параметра **ratelimit** можно ограничить количество отправляемых сообщений. Но только когда наступает лимит, при попытке отправки сообщения оно даже не добавляется в очередь, а сразу отклоняется (например PHP функция **mail()** возвращает **false**). В связи с этим сообщения просто теряются.

Вопрос, как настроить Exim4, чтобы сообщения всегда добавлялись в очередь отправки, но только ограничить скорость обработки сообщений из очереди?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно ограничивать не приём сообщений, а отправку сообщений из очереди:

```
queue_run_max = 5
remote_max_parallel = 1
queue_smtp_domains = 1
```

[Описание директив.](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-exim4-users/2007-March/000955.html)